# Coloring part of a link?

Tags: colors, hyperlink

I have a small problem with coloring a part of my link. The whole link is colored with a pattern, but i want the first part to be colored with another pattern.

Here is my html

```
<div id="header-wrap">
        <div id="header">
            <nav>
           <ul>
                    <li id="mig"><a href="#mig">#Om mig</a></li>    
                    <li id="portfolio"><a href="#portfolio">#Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li id="kontakt"><a href="#kontakt">#Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What i want to fill with a another pattern is the ´#´ in front of the rest of the text.

Here is my css:

```
#header nav li {
display: inline;
font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
color: white;  /* Fallback: assume this color ON TOP of image */
background: url(../img/debut_light.png) repeat;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-moz-background-clip: text;
-moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
background-clip: text;
text-fill-color: transparent;
}

nav #hjem {
margin-right: 530px;
}

nav #mig {
margin-right: 50px;
}

nav #portfolio {
margin-right: 50px;
} 

nav #kontakt {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

enclose the hash # between span tag

HTML

```
<a href="#"><span>#</span>Portfolio</a>
```

CSS

```
a span{
    color:black;
 }
```

Comment: Sadly it doesnt work. I dont know why? Could it be because I am using a pattern to color the link?

Comment: honestly i didnt understood what u mean by 'pattern'.. i dont see  any such code for pattern.i assumed by pattern u simply meant other color..can u be more precise